# Which treatment approaches for compulsive overeating are most effective?"

Tags: eating-disorder, emotional-eating

I have a habit of eating too much of food. Whenever I start to eat any meal I don't think of quantity and I eat till I finish the plate even if I am full. I feel like I am eating mindlessly or sometimes I feel I have the stamina to eat more. Is there any effective treatment approach?

Comment: I feel like this should be asked at Psychology.SE...

Comment: We are not quite there yet, i.e., a [proposed Psychology.SE](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102503/psychology) is in the _Definition_ stage. We need 30 more questions with a score of 10 to move to the _Commitment_ phase. If you (anyone reading this) want to help, read [Someone proposed a great site. How do I get involved?](https://area51.stackexchange.com/faq) and visit the [Psychology page](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102503/psychology) to give an upvote to five questions!

Comment: Consider rephrasing your question to something like, "Which treatment approaches for compulsive overeating are most effective?"

Comment: I suggest rephrasing the question since, "If your question is requesting personal medical advice, it is off-topic and instead should be directed to your personal physician." ==> _See:_ [What topics can I ask about here?](https://health.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in the [Help Center](https://health.stackexchange.com/help).

Comment: @Carey Gregory - I am in the process of writing an answer. Thank you for asking the question as I have wanted to review the literature in this area for a while, but had not yet done so.

Comment: @MarkDWorthenPsyD I think you meant thank you for editing the question since I didn't ask it. You're welcome.

Comment: @Carey Gregory - Well, good golly Miss Molly! Right you are. Yes, thank you for the edit! And _Javed Ahmed_ - see above for the thank you meant for you.  ;O)

Comment: @MarkDWorthenPsyD Thanks for the comments. Kindly answer it.